# How can I put multiple `join` field in one Elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am saving employee data in Elasticsearch7. There are parent-child relationship (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html) I am trying to use that to build the relationship in my data.

There are different relationship I need to support based on employee's role.

```
one team manager can manage multiple employees
one HR manager can manage multiple employees
```

the challenge part about the relation is that one employ has two managers (HR manager and team manager). But Elasticsearch only support one join field per index and one child can only have one parent in the relationship. Based on that, how can I solve this issue in Elasticsearch?

Comment: What do you think about denormalizing the data ?

Comment: `denormalizing` means to save the relationship document as a nested json object.

Comment: Yes, you would have something along those lines `{"employe_details"{...}, "hr_manager": {...}, "manager": {...}}` each employee will have te info of his manager. it is called deduplication because you have many many time the same information about the manager for all the employee the manager manage.

Comment: Not an elegant, nor very optimised solution. But Es does not really work well with relationship